# How do you get the membership profile of a user in an ASP.NET MVC3 razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using the following snippet worked just fine in mvc2:

```
<%= Profile %>
```

But in my razor view I do not have access to Profile. Where do I get it from now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
@{
    var profile = Context.Profile;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I only had to cast it to my own profileclass (which I did not have to do before) but hey, it does the trick.